# Posting to API with curl not working

Tags: php, curl

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($result);


curl_close($curl);
```

I have the code above, i want to post to an api. Somehow its not working. I tried using a var_dump on the result variable. The result is:

```
string(117) "{"Message":"The request entity's media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported for this resource."}"
```

Any idea why its not posting to the api?

The value of the $post=

```
{"AmountDebit":10,"Currency":"EUR","Invoice":"testinvoice 123","Services":{"ServiceList":[{"Action":"Pay","Name":"ideal","Parameters":[{"Name":"issuer","Value":"ABNANL2A"}]}]}}
```

Headers:

```
$headers[] = 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;
```

Comment: did you try googling that message?

Comment: what is the value of `$post`? is it a string or an array? By default `CURLOPT_POST` sets the header as described but you can change the format of the data sent to an array and it will send in `multipart/form-data`

Comment: What is `$headers`?

Comment: @RamRaider added it to my question

Comment: @AjAX. added it to my question

Comment: Sorry was off. But where does the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` come from?

Comment: Add a `content-type:text/html` `header`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a `Content-Type` header when making a POST call with Curl, it will add one in with the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

From the [**Everything Curl** book](https://ec.haxx.se/http-post.html):

> POSTing with curl's -d option will make it include a default header that looks like Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. That's what your typical browser will use for a plain POST.
>
> Many receivers of POST data don't care about or check the Content-Type header.
>
> If that header is not good enough for you, you should, of course, replace that and instead provide the correct one.

Judging by your request, I imagine you'll need to add the following to the top of your script:

```
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
```

But depending on the exact API you're posting to, this might need to be different.

Answer (score -2):

Have You installed curl before using it.
If it not install try google for Curl installation
and use my curl function for post request its 100% working-

```
public function curlPostJson() {
    $headers = [];
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' .strlen(json_encode($paramdata));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($paramdata));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($server_output);
}
```

Comment: If the OP hadn't installed cURL, he would not receive any result